# How to determine the time it took SmtpClient.send to send the message?

Tags: c#

@Title

How do I determine the time it took to send the message?

Right now, when I click "send", my program simply is silent. I would like the program to show something like a progress bar that will load while the program is sending the message.

Is that possible?

As of the moment, this is what I have:

```
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getEmail, connect.connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", sectionSelect.SelectedValue);

                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                System.Data.DataTable mailingList = new System.Data.DataTable();

                adapter.Fill(mailingList);

                foreach (DataRow row in mailingList.Rows)
                {
                    string rows = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
                    message.To.Add(rows);
                }

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password.Password);
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.Port = 587;
                client.EnableSsl = true;

                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your message has been sent.");
            }
```

Comment: A progress bar would be wasteful because `SmtpClient.Send` doesn't report intermediate status.

Comment: Too bad. I just wanted something that the user can see while the program is sending the messages. Is there a way to relate the progress bar to the try instead? I mean, load until all the procedures in TRY is done?

Comment: Of course. Show it before the try, and hide it in the finally.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, when I click "send", my program simply is silent.

`SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage)` is not an asynchronous call, and will consequently block the calling thread until the operation is completed.

Alternatively, you can send the message with [SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) which will make the call asynchronously, allowing you to display any sort of wait dialog you want until the send completes.

You can then set up a callback function that reports the operation as complete to the user. There is a good example of this in the MSDN article I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You could launch this process on the UI thread and update a progress bar half way through you method above (or at several points), but this is not the ideal way of doing this. You would ideally want (depending on how long each message takes or indeed how many messages you were sending) launch your working process on a separate thread.

Note: *this may be overkill if this is not a sufficiently long running process*.

An easy way into using threading is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). So assuming this is a sufficiently long running procedure or something you may extend in the future to sending multiple messages in one batch you could launch this on a background thread as follows:

```
    using System.Threading;

    // Threading.
    private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
    AutoResetEvent areProgressChanged = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private void SendYourMessage()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getEmail, connect.connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", sectionSelect.SelectedValue);
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            // Show your progress.
            (bgWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progressBarValue, "Half Way through...");

            DataTable mailingList = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(mailingList);

            foreach (DataRow row in mailingList.Rows)
            {
                string rows = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
                message.To.Add(rows);
            }

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password.Password);
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeTaken = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your message has been sent. That took {0}s", timeTaken.Seconds));
        } 
    }

    private void SendMyMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start job on new thread.
        bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
        bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWorker_ProgressChanged);
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker thisWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        SendYourMessage();
    }

    void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change progress bar (and form label).
        this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        this.label.Text = e.UserState;

        // Tell the worker that the UIThread has been updated.
        this.areProgressChanged.Set();
        return;
    }

    // Once the work is complete do something.
    void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle.
        if (e.Cancelled || bgWorker.CancellationPending)
            MessageBox.Show("Message cancelled at users request!");
        else if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error: {0}.", e.Error.ToString()));
        return;
    }

    // To cancel the job.
    private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
            bgWorker.CancelAsync();
    }
```

This code may need tweaking. Essentially you set up some event to launch your process (here the `SomeEvent_Click` event) and this is the entry point to the `BackgroundgroundWorker`, the rest of the events I use here you can read about on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Good luck.